# Putting some calculations together to form an algorithm

Tags: function-construction, algorithm, modular-arithmetic

Considering these below where `n` is an odd number, `k` is also an odd number less than `n`:

```
In[56]:= Table[PowerMod[2 a + 1, (n ± 1)/2, n], {a, 1, k}];
In[57]:= Table[2 a + 1, {a, 1, k}];
In[58]:= Mod[%56, %57];
In[59]:= Select[%, # == 0 &]
Out[59]= {0}
```

How do I put all these together into an algorithm that will work for any number `n`?

Comment: Are you asking how to make a function/module/block that does all of the above for any odd n? Or how to extend it to even n as well?

Comment: @MariusLadegårdMeyer, I am asking how to make a function/module/block that does all of the above for any odd n in Mathematica.

Comment: Then read the docs for `Module` :) It should be self explainatory.

Comment: @MariusLadegårdMeyer, I have read them but am finding it difficult to implement it in this case. Can you help me do the application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As requested in comments, a demo:

```
algo[n_?OddQ, k_?OddQ] /; k < n := Module[{x, y},
  x = Table[PowerMod[2 a + 1, (n + 1)/2, n], {a, 1, k}];
  y = Table[2 a + 1, {a, 1, k}];
  Select[Mod[x, y], # == 0 &]
  ]
```

The character ± does not have any built-in meaning in *Mathematica*, so I chose + in the demo. You will need to implement some decision on whether to use + or - yourself :)

Also, you do realize that `Select[list, # == 0 &]` will always output a list of 0's right? I don't know how useful that is... If you want to know how many are zeros, use `Count[list, 0]` instead.